# how to add map in an android activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to add map in an activity, but not getting it work! I tried using [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) tutorial link.
Also I tried to add it through a View Map link in on activity. Please somebody help me.
Here is my code snippet with the logcat:

MainActivity.java
    package com.example.map;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.map.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyB2mLtP5XYhIq1KB1TEhE60wlcDxQSeUWA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: @KrupaPatel Your suggested edits are inappropriate. **DO NOT** do any of the following: (1) Bold topic words (2) Copy body content as the edit summary (3) Use quote formatting for things that aren't quotes. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267449

Answer (score 1):

Your min sdk is 8.

Change this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

The metatag must be a child of Application tag in manifest.

```
... //rest of the code
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyB2mLtP5XYhIq1KB1TEhE60wlcDxQSeUWA" />
</application>
```

You are missing one more metag tag in manifest

```
<meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> // missing
```

You can get rid of

```
<permission
android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: i tried your answer but the emulator is throwing an error as "This app won't work without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone"

Comment: @Web you need  google play services apk installed on the device which is available on 4.2.2 or later or test it on a real device. One more thing check if your device has google play services apk installed before runnin map in the app

Comment: my android version is 4.4.2. I need to install google play services apk?

Comment: @web try it on a real device

Comment: @Web and read  https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. Google map is part of google play services. **The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher**.

Comment: I have downloaded google play services apk from here: http://gappsearly.com/component/jdownloads/summary/31-google-play-services/139-google-play-services.html?Itemid=470.  Now where should I add it?

Comment: @Web nothing to do test it on a real device